# Should functions be attached to object or its prototype?

Tags: javascript, object, prototype, new-operator, ecmascript-5

I am learning javascript and I am wondering about the concept of functions and prototypes inside an object.

**My understanding of the concept**

As I understand it, functions should be attached to object's prototype in order to allocate less memory.

For example (if what I said is true), both version will do the same job but second version will allocate less memory:

```
var collectionOfObjects = [];
for(var i=0; i<1000; i++){
    collectionOfObjects.push({id: 2, sayHi: function(){console .log('hi')}})
}
//vs
function Foobar(id){
    this.id = id || 0;
}
Foobar.prototype.sayHi = function(){
    console.log('hi');
}
var otherCollection = [];
for(var i=0; i<1000; i++){
    otherCollection.push(new Foobar());
}
```

**Question**

```
//this attaches sayHi function to the object instead of its prototype
var foobar = {
    id: 0,
    sayHi: function(){
        console.log('Hi');
    }
}
```

Since I shouldn't use `__proto__`, how do I attach `sayHi` function to foobar's prototype instead of foobar object? I assume that adding `sayHi` to `Object.prototype` isn't a good solution as it would add `sayHi` function to every object.

Comment: You should segregate your questions

Comment: You should also probably check out some modern tutorials, because these are questions that make sense back in the "we only have functions and prototypes" days, but these days (unless you already know what you're doing) there's no good reason to not just use modern class syntax instead, which makes these questions entirely moot: functions go in your class, and there is no "constructor function" that you manually attach a prototype to, so there is nothing to decide. There's only one place things go.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I am asking this question just in case I have to work with some legacy code. But I am gald to hear that this isn't a problem when using class syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The prototype chain is setup via the `new` keyword, a `class` or `Object.create()`. Either way, it's set when the object is created.

So you already know one way, which is is to add functions to the prototype of a constructor function and instantiate with `new`.

The modern way would be to use a `class`, but you specifically mention legacy code here, so I'm going to assume that's out for purposes of this discussion.

The last way is to use `Object.create()` which gives you an object with some prototype:

```
var myProto = {
  // There is only one of this function, ever.
  sayHi: function() {
    console.log('hi');
  }
}

var otherCollection = [];
for(var i=0; i<1000; i++){
    var obj = Object.create(myProto)
    obj.id = i // or other custom setup.
    otherCollection.push(obj);
}
```

---

That said, in modern javascript engines having unique functions per object is not a big deal. I've worked on some pretty large javascript apps and memory usage due to the number of function instances has not ever been a performance bottleneck at all.

In modern React with functional hooks, for instance, it would be incredibly cumbersome (if not impossible in some cases) to avoid creating hundreds of new functions on every render. It's designed to be that way and it still performs very well. And if it doesn't perform well, it's never due to too many functions.

Answer (score 3):

You understanding is accurate. Objects created with the `obj = { ... }` notation inherit from `Object.prototype`, and changing their prototype with `__proto__` or its modern equivalent `Object.setPrototypeOf` is especially slow in all JavaScript implementations. But there is another way to set the prototype of an object on creation.

The `Object.create(proto)` function lets you create an object which inherits from `proto`, so you don't have to use the confusing `Foobar.prototype` syntax and the magical `new` operator.

```
let Foobar = {
  id: 0,
  sayHi: function() {
    console.log('Hi');
  }
};

let obj = Object.create(Foobar);
obj.id = 1;
obj.sayHi(); // Hi
```

If you had a dozen properties to set on `obj`, having to assign each property manually after the object creation would be a bit lame, but you can use the nifty `Object.assign` function for that:

```
let Elephant = {
  name: 'an elephant',
  ears: 'boring',
  sayHi: function() {
    console.log(`Hi, I am ${this.name} and my ears are ${this.ears}.`);
  }
};

let dumbo = Object.assign(Object.create(Elephant), {
  name: 'Dumbo',
  ears: 'AWESOME'
});

dumbo.sayHi(); // Hi, I am Dumbo and my ears are AWESOME.
```

If you wanted to create a bunch of objects and give them all the same 3 methods, you could therefore replace this:

```
let t = { name: "Tom", eat, sleep, repeat };
let g = { name: "Garfield", eat, sleep, repeat };
```

with this:

```
let protoCat = { eat, sleep, repeat };
let t = Object.assign(Object.create(protoCat), { name: "Tom" });
let g = Object.assign(Object.create(protoCat), { name: "Garfield });
```

It would be more practical, however, to have some kind of constructor function instead. Using `Object.assign` for a single property is a bit overkill so I'll simplify this next example:

```
function cat(name) {
    const c = Object.create(protoCat);
    c.name = name;
    return c;
}

let t = cat("Tom");
let t = cat("Garfield");
```

Note that you don't call `cat` with `new`, since cat builds its own object. If you tried calling `cat` with the `new` operator here, it would create an object which inherits from the empty `cat.prototype`, but that object would eventually be discarded since `cat` has a return value.

UPDATE: While my answer gives a pretty complete explanation of how `prototype` works, I feel like I failed to point out that you don't have to use it at all. You could very well just assign the methods every time.

```
function cat(name) {
    return { name, eat, sleep, repeat };
}
```

Sure, all your cats now hold a reference to all their methods, which might take a tiny bit of extra memory, but writing hard to maintain code to save a few bytes isn't what I'd call an optimization.

JavaScript likes to treat objects like data, in a way similar to lisp, and if you just pretend it has classes, you might end up wishing you were using another language.

Comment: PS: there's no need to use `var` at all if you're on a modern browser, `let` and `const` are your friends!

Answer (score 2):

As Mike said in the comments, pseudo-classical inheritance has been deprecated by classes in ES2015 (ES6) and beyond, so `Foobar.prototype` should be discarted.

You allocate less memory by reusing a function definition instead of defining the function for every object you create. This can be done with `Footbar.prototype`, plain prototypes, classes, or a simple function definition without inheritance. As usual, JavaScript provides many ways to achieve the same goal, it is up to you which one you choose.

Your question already contains a pseudo-classical way to do it, you can also use a `class` or a plain prototype:

```js
var footbarProptotype = {
    sayHi: function() {
        console.log('Hi');
    }
};

var footbar = Object.create(footbarProptotype);

footbar.sayHi()
```

And you can reuse the function definition yourself without using any kind of inheritance

```
function sayHi(){
    console.log('hi');
}

var collectionOfObjects = [];

for(var i=0; i<1000; i++){
    collectionOfObjects.push({ sayHi: sayHi });
}
```

The memory optimization only comes from defining the function only once and reusing that definition every time you can.